# SQL - replace value in SELECT clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database column and it's values:

```
Column
#1 747, 757, 767
#2 747, 757
#3 767, 777
...
```

I want to query this table with a SQL SELECT and the output should be something like this:

```
#1 Tree, Beer, Car
#2 Tree, Beer
#3 Car, House
```

So I need to kind of translate the numeric codes in words. How can I achieve this in a select clause?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have another table with the values of `Tree`, `Beer` etc etc associated with the numbers

Comment: @Torben Create another table with tree,beer,car etc and add that table's id or any column value as the foreign key to the main table and then just do an join in the select query.

Comment: Is that a table with thos numbers in a comma delimited list? If so **bad design** I suggest you redesign the database

Comment: is this single column?

Comment: Hi @JaydipJ I think it is a single column ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try that

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE #temp (COL1 VARCHAR(50))


INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('#1 747, 757, 767'),
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('#2 747, 757'),
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('#3 767, 777')


SELECT replace(
replace(
replace(
replace(COL1, '747', 'Tree'), 
'757', 'Beer'), 
'777', 'House'), 
'767', 'Car') required_value 
FROM #temp
```

Should I mention the table design can be improved by putting the values in different columns.

If you are planning to undo your current design and have another one, you will need testing but I guess it is not the aim of the question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It will be very bad to hardcode like this but this is the only way now in my head

```
Select 
COLUMN1, 
CASE COLUMN2 WHEN 747 THEN 'TREE' WHEN 757 THEN 'BEER' WHEN 767 THEN 'CAR' WHEN 777 THEN 'HOUSE' END AS COLUMN2,
CASE COLUMN3 WHEN 747 THEN 'TREE' WHEN 757 THEN 'BEER' WHEN 767 THEN 'CAR' WHEN 777 THEN 'HOUSE' END AS COLUMN3,
CASE COLUMN4 WHEN 747 THEN 'TREE' WHEN 757 THEN 'BEER' WHEN 767 THEN 'CAR' WHEN 777 THEN 'HOUSE' END AS COLUMN4
FROM YOURTABLE
```