# Substring replacement

Tags: sql

I have string values like below

```
002 - KLAMPFER - Sy 52-5-5+L
002 - KLMGEEDD - SR 53-5-5+L
002 - LREFDGRE - SU 54-5 etc...
```

I want to make this like below output

```
002 - XXXXXXX - Sy 52-5-5+L
002 - XXXXXXX - SR 53-5-5+L
002 - XXXXXXX - SU 54-5
```

I tried but I did not get the output expected.
I am looking for substring function with replace.

Comment: Do you want to permanently change the values or just run a SELECT that does this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - replace value in SELECT clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742362/sql-replace-value-in-select-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use regular expressions.

In Oracle the following SQL statement worked for me:

```
select regexp_replace('002 - KLAMPFER - Sy 52-5-5+L', '- [A-Z]+ -', '- XXXXXXX -')
  from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can use `update`:

```
update t
    set col2 = 'XXXXXXX'
    where col2 = 'KLAMPFER';
```

If that value is a *single* string, then:

```
update t
    set col = replace(col, 'KLAMPFER', 'XXXXXXX')
    where col like '%KLAMPFER%';
```

Comment: Here "KLAMPFER" is not same all the time it will change. Actaully I am looking for Substring Function which will handle this as want to use this in ETL tool matillion.

Comment: @user2795318 . . . This answers the question you originally asked.  It is better to ask a *new* question rather than invalidating answers.